# Best way to pull GAE Datastore data as a list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking for the best way to pull info from the datastore into a list (with the intention of outputting to ReportLab to generate a pdf).  Is there a way to do it besides looping through the output, and creating a list from it?

Answer (score 2):

Per [the source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py?spec=svn87&r=87#1567) [`fetch()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_fetch) returns a list:

> Returns:   A list of db.Model
>   instances...

The results of that query will look something like this:

```
[<models.YourModel object at 0x02641B30>, 
<models.YourModel object at 0x02641B70>]
```

Edit:
And then to get certain attributes of the model instances you'd do something like this:

```
values = [(model.name, model.type, model.source) 
          for model 
          in models_returned_from_query]
```

I don't know of any further shortcut for the above.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the results themselves, not just the object instances.  For ex: [['john', 'cat', 'store'],['charlie','dog','shelter']]